# Why does nested each in template output nothing

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

While this is rendered as expected:

```
{{#each Items}}  // a collection
  {{title}}  
{{/each}}  
{{#each types}}  // another ollection
  {{refId}}  
{{/each}}
```

if I put it together:

```
{{#each Items}}  
  {{title}}  
  {{#each types}}  
    {{refId}}  
  {{/each}} 
{{/each}}
```

The `#each types` is empty.

The template helpers:

```
Template.menuItems.helpers({
    restMenuItems: function() {
        return RestMenuItems.find({restRefId: this._id}, {sort:Template.instance().sort.get()});
    },
    restMenuSideItems: function() {
        return RestMenuSideItems.find({restRefId: this._id},            {sort:Template.instance().sort.get()});
    }
});

Template.menuItems.onCreated( function(){
    this.subscribe('restMenuItems');
    this.subscribe('restMenuSideItems');
});
```

And some of the template code:

```html
{{#each restMenuItems}}
  <div>
    <select class="list-group select_side_addons">
      {{#each restMenuSideItems}}
        <option>{{restRefId}}</option>
      {{/each}}
    </select>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Even when replacing `{{#each restMenuSideItems}}` by `{{#each ../restMenuSideItems}}`, nothing appears.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `#each` clause changes the data context to the current item.

If you want a list of `types` inside each of the `Items`, you can get the parent data context using `..`.

If `types` is an attribute of the parent context:

```handlebars
{{#each Items}}  
  {{title}}  
  {{#each ../types}}  
    {{refId}}  
  {{/each}} 
{{/each}}
```

If `types` is a template helper, you can pass the parent context as an argument to it:

```
{{#each Items}}  
  {{title}}  
  {{#each types ..}}  
    {{refId}}  
  {{/each}} 
{{/each}}
```

and use the context for your query.

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({

  types: function(parent) {
    // you now have the parent context here.
    // use parent._id etc. where you used this._id in the
    // "flat" version.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still the same.

Comment: Strange, that should work. Can you provide more code (e.g, your helpers and more complete template code)? Where do `Items` and `types` come from?

Comment: Just did.  @MasterAM

Comment: With a different collection inside the each it works without the need to use the ../, I guess because they don't have fields with the same keys.

Comment: The issue is likely not with it being the same/different collection, but with the fact that it is a helper using the data context for the query. Passing the parent data context as a parameter should do it.